# How do I create Observable from an array of samples?

Tags: java, rx-java, observable

Let's suppose we have some buffer of samples read from a sensor. The buffer is fed with new samples each time I run a method on it (i.e. `buffer.fetchNewSamples()`). How would I create Java Rx Observable from such object that would return each sample from the buffer one by one and call `buffer.fetchNewSamples()` when last sample is emitted and then continue in the same manner?

I'm just starting with Rx and while it was pretty easy to create an observable that returns i.e. average of such buffer, I have no idea how could I create the thing described above without creating new thread and do some synchronization...

Comment: Can't you just wire up the sensor with RxJava directly?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe I can. How do I do that?

Comment: It depends on how the sensor API looks like. Is it like a blocking call for a reading, callback based or perhaps gives you an array of measurements?

Comment: The call is probably blocking as it just fills a float array buffer with new samples (buffer size is determined by sensor type) and I can read new samples straight away. I call fetch on this sensor each 10 ms. Wouldn't an observable that iterates such buffer and calls onNext for each array element and then fetchNewSamples somehow be an unusable, (infinitely looping) observable?

Comment: So do you want to trigger measurements based on consumption or time?

Comment: I would need a steady flow of sensor data, this will be for a robot that observes this data and does certain things when some specific patterns in the data occur. So I would say, It's based on time. It's like assembly line robot. The assembly line doesn't wait, just runs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a single sensory API `float[] measure()`, you can do timed measurements and emission via the following sequence:

```
Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .onBackpressureDrop()
    .map(t -> measure())
    .concatMap(fa -> Observable.range(0, fa.length).map(i -> fa[i]))
.subscribe(...)
```

**Explanation**

Given an interval of 10ms, drop anything non-requested and map the timer value to an array of the measured values (this happens every 10ms). Given the array of measurements, emitted one after another, flatten it to its array elements via the equivalent of an indexed for loop, but make sure the next measurement value comes only after the previous has finished emitting the array elements. At the end, you have a stream of floats.

If you want to measure immediately once all measurements from the previous call has been consumed, you can do the following:

```
BehaviorSubject<Integer> bs = BehaviorSubject.create(1);

bs.observeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
.map(t -> measure())
.concatMap(fa -> 
    Observable.range(0, fa.length).map(i -> fa[i])
    .finallyDo(() -> bs.onNext(1))
)
```

**Explanation**
We utilize the behavior of BehaviorSubject to emit its stored value to the first subscriber and we will use it for triggering measurements. To avoid infinite recursion, we will observe the subject on the trampoline scheduler. Once a signal comes through, we take the measurement and turn it into a sequence of floats like above. The only difference is that whenever such sub-sequence completes, it will signal the BehaviorSubject to trigger another measurement.

Comment: I'd appreciate a bit of explanation, though.